# CV2 Setting frames resulting in NoneType object

Tags: python, opencv, video, motion-detection

I have code which selects 50 random frames from a video and then finds the median of them, to make a background image.

This works with many of my videos, however it does not work for one of them and I am not sure why. All videos are in .avi format.

The problem video results in an error, "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". The reason for this error (I think) is that when setting the frame ID to read the 50 random frames, I get a few which are NoneType objects, which does not happen for my other videos. This means I have problems later when finding the median.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

edit: further information, the nonetype frames are the ones with indexes quite high eg any with an index 800 and up. But according to cv2 there should be 1019 frames in total, so not sure why this is a problem

```
def get_background(file_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
    # we will randomly select 50 frames for the calculating the median
    frame_indices = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) * np.random.uniform(size=50)
    # we will store the frames in array
    frames = []

    for idx in frame_indices:
        # set the frame id to read that particular frame
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, idx)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frames.append(frame)
# calculate the median
median_frame = np.median(frames, axis=0).astype(np.uint8)

return median_frame
```

Comment: Using the status of `ret` you can decide whether you want to append the frame to the list or not.

Comment: But surely I would want to append all 50 frames? In the code I find the total number of frames, then pull out 50 random ones to average. This works for all my other videos. Just this one, which has more frames in it, the frames it pulls twards the end of the videos (but within range of its total frames) it has a problem, like it doesn't really exist.

Comment: are you able to play the video properly?

Comment: Using your suggestion I put append in a if ret == True loop, and now it works, I just would like to know why cv2 thinks there are more frames than there actually is

Comment: No as I'm in spyder which doesn't support video play, but using imshow I can display the frames in the plot viewer so it is definitely reading the frames

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.